# Scrollbar in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to put a scrollbar in a canvas inside a Frame with tkinter. I can see my scrollbar but she don't work. I don't anderstant why, here is my code.

```
    labelBlesser = tk.Label(self.fen, text='Rajouter', font=fontLabel)
    labelBlesser.configure(background='white')
    labelBlesser.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.40, anchor='center')

    frameBlesser = tk.Frame(self.fen)

    vbar = tk.Scrollbar(frameBlesser, orient='vertical')
    vbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    canvasBlesser = tk.Canvas(frameBlesser)
    vbar.config(command=canvasBlesser.yview)

    frameBlesser.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.65, anchor='center')

    for _ in range(3):
        self.listeBlesser.append(tk.Label(canvasBlesser, text='Blesse {}:'.format(self.nombreBlesserAjouter + 1)))
        self.listeBlesser.append(tk.Entry(canvasBlesser, font=fontEntry))

    self.refreshListeBlesser()
    canvasBlesser.pack()


def refreshListeBlesser(self):
    for i, lab in enumerate(self.listeBlesser):
        lab.place(x=10, y=i*70+13)
```

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the canvas and the scrollbar together. Also, you need to create a frame inside of the canvas using `canvasBlesser.create_window` so that you can place stuff inside the frame as usual.

```py
frameBlesser = tk.Frame(self.fen)
vbar = tk.Scrollbar(frameBlesser, orient='vertical')
vbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
canvasBlesser = tk.Canvas(frameBlesser)
# adding the side and fill for packing canvas in the frame
canvasBlesser.pack(side='left', fill='both')

# connecting the canvas and scrollbar together
vbar.config(command=canvasBlesser.yview)
canvasBlesser.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

# placing a frame inside the canvas as a parent to other widgets in it
inner_frame = tk.Frame(canvasBlesser)
canvasBlesser.create_window((0,0), window=inner_frame, anchor="nw")
```

Use this `inner_frame` as a parent to place the widgets just as usual to be seen in the canvas.

The line `canvasBlesser.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)` makes it so that whenever the view of the canvas is changed, it updates the scrollbar's value.

Comment: Hello thank you but I have an error:
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func()
TypeError: set() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first' and 'last'`

Comment: can you post the complete exception. and what line exactly is the error on (pasting the complete traceback would do)

Comment: that's the problem it's already the complete exception
`D:\Projet\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projet/main.py
aze
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func()
TypeError: set() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first' and 'last'
`

Comment: can you try placing the `canvasBlesser.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)` line before `vbar.config(command=canvasBlesser.yview)` and then come back?

Comment: Nop same error :(
`D:\Projet\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projet/main.py
aze
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func()
TypeError: set() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first' and 'last'`